# git hook flake8: error: input not specified

Tags: python, git, githooks, flake8

Flake8's `pre-commit` hook for git raises `flake8: error: input not specified` whenever I do git commit.

The hook file is identical to the [official example](https://flake8.readthedocs.org/en/2.0/vcs.html#git-hook) :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from flake8.run import git_hook

COMPLEXITY = 10
STRICT = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(git_hook(complexity=COMPLEXITY, strict=STRICT, ignore='E501'))
```

Comment: What a `flake8 -v` returns?

Comment: Hi, @VonC, just tried, it returns the same error..

Comment: @VonC, and `flake8 --version` gives `2.1.0 (pep8: 1.4.6, mccabe: 0.2.1, pyflakes: 0.7.3) CPython 2.7.3 on Linux`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is due to a bug in flake8 2.1.0.  To work around this, create an empty setup.cfg or tox.ini file in your project directory.  I just created a bug ticket for this: https://bitbucket.org/tarek/flake8/issue/133/git_hook-broken-when-setupcfg-and-toxini

Answer (score 2):

There was a similar bug on a previous flake8 version ([issue 68](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/flake8/issue/68/syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-parser), fixed by [commit 8fe9bfb](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/flake8/commits/8fe9bfb))

But a very recent version of flake8 might have re-introduced that bug again ([tweet, 6:02 PM - 20 Nov 13](https://twitter.com/robhudson/status/403206667765960704)):

> I'm not sure what happened to flake8 after update.
>   My old trusty pre-commit hook now returns, "`flake8: error: input not specified`".

---

The [OP dlutxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922727/dlutxx) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296392/git-hook-flake8-error-input-not-specified#comment30287047_20297640):

> until they fixed this bug, **I'll just append the source directory to `sys.argv` within the pre-commit file**.
>   Ugly, but [it] works.

Comment: Well, until they fixed this bug, I'll just append the source directory to `sys.argv` within the pre-commit file. Ugly, but works.

Comment: @dlutxx good workaround. I have added that to the answer for more visibility.